# select sheets excel

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

XE3 use delphi with excel ole automation.
With this code I open and read / write in the cells, but I can not select different sheets (Sheet1, Sheet3 etc.)

```
begin
L_vi.Caption: = 'D: \ bd1 \ file_supporto \ Vi.xls';
Ex: = createoleobject ('Excel.Application');
Ex.visible: = true;
Ex.workbooks.open (L_vi.Caption);
Ex.cells [1,1]: = 'test';
Sheets: = Ex.Workbooks [1]. Worksheets ['Sheet3'];
```

Can you help?

thanks

P.S.
i resolved so:

```
Ex.Workbooks [1]. Worksheets ['Sheet3'].select;
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works well for me in XE3:

```
var
  XLApp: OleVariant;
  Sheet: OleVariant;
begin
  XLApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  XLApp.Visible := True;
  XLApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\Test\Testing.xls');
  ShowMessage(XLApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1].Name);  // Sheet1
  Sheet := XLApp.Worksheets.Item['Sheet3']; 
  ShowMessage(Sheet.Name);                             // Sheet3
  Sheet.Select;
  // This also works
  XLApp.WorkSheets.Item['Sheet1'].Select;              // Sheet1
end;
```